# Looking for a audio Analysis library for information extraction

Tags: feature-extraction, audio-analysis, pyaudioanalysis

Hey guys I'm a beginner in Audio Analysis and trying to find a library which gives me insights like amplitude, classification of sound, what should detect background noise. I have tried out Paura/pyAudioAnalysis ([pAura: Python AUdio Recording and Analysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/paura)) which analyzes some of the information for live recording. Is there any good audio analysis library in GitHub   ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many. search for DTLN model for audio noise removal on github. DTLN is a pretrained noise removal lite model.

if you're not planning to use any models then try to fix this problem using audio signal processing. use audio features like zero crossing rate for noise/speech activity detection.